# How to cycle through terminal autocomplete suggestions without pressing ENTER key?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, autocomplete

In a scenario like following:

```
sudo apt install a
```

(press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice)

```
Display all 1244 possibilities? (y or n)
```

(press <kbd>Y</kbd>)

(It shows me a list where I can keep seeing more by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
abiword-common
abiword-plugin-grammar
ableton-link-dev
--More--
```

Every <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress shows one more line. And if I held down <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, at some point it would reach to the end of the list and execute `sudo apt install a` by mistake.

It is harmless in this scenario but it could have executed something bad if I was cycling through a list of directories while doing some `rm -rf foo`

Is there a more efficient and safe way of scrolling through autocomplete recommendations output list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move forward in such a case. <kbd>Enter</kbd> moves only one line up and that is inefficient, and a waste of time for me.

Use <kbd>Space</kbd> which moves a whole screen ahead and there is no danger of executing unwanted command.